# Couldn't use Nvidia Driver in Kubuntu 22.10 after upgrade from 22.04

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-prime

Today I upgraded my Kubuntu from 22.04 to 22.10 and I couldn’t manage to use my Nvidia yet. Anyone happened the same? Any clues about what could be happening?

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.25.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.98.0
Qt Version: 5.15.6
Kernel Version: 5.19.0-21-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 12 × Intel® Core™ i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
Memory: 31.2 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630
Manufacturer: SchenkerTechnologiesGmbH
Product Name: XMG Mobile A507 VE
System Version: Not Applicable


ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
(nvidia-settings:3714): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 12:51:12.530: g_object_unref: assertion ‘G_IS_OBJECT (object)’ failed
** (nvidia-settings:3714): CRITICAL **: 12:51:12.531: ctk_powermode_new: assertion ‘(ctrl_target != NULL) && (ctrl_target->h != NULL)’ failed
ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file or the X server is not accessible. This file should have been installed along with this driver at /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The application
profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text. Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
** Message: 12:51:12.583: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 12:51:12.583: PRIME: is it supported? yes
** Message: 12:51:12.610: PRIME: Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|on-demand|query
** Message: 12:51:12.610: PRIME: on-demand mode: “1”
** Message: 12:51:12.610: PRIME: is “on-demand” mode supported? yes

nvidia-xconfig
Using X configuration file: “/etc/X11/xorg.conf”.
VALIDATION ERROR: Data incomplete in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.
Device section “Device0” must have a Driver line.
WARNING: Unable to parse X.Org version string.
Package xorg-server was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xorg-server.pc’
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package ‘xorg-server’ found
ERROR: Unable to find any GPUs in the system.

lspci -v | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn’t communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes adicionales:
  libnvidia-cfg1-515 libnvidia-common-515 libnvidia-compute-515 libnvidia-compute-515:i386 libnvidia-decode-515 libnvidia-decode-515:i386 libnvidia-encode-515 libnvidia-encode-515:i386 libnvidia-extra-515 libnvidia-fbc1-515
  libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 libnvidia-gl-515 libnvidia-gl-515:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-515 nvidia-dkms-515 nvidia-kernel-common-515 nvidia-kernel-source-515 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-515 screen-resolution-extra
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes NUEVOS:
  libnvidia-cfg1-515 libnvidia-common-515 libnvidia-compute-515 libnvidia-compute-515:i386 libnvidia-decode-515 libnvidia-decode-515:i386 libnvidia-encode-515 libnvidia-encode-515:i386 libnvidia-extra-515 libnvidia-fbc1-515
  libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 libnvidia-gl-515 libnvidia-gl-515:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-515 nvidia-dkms-515 nvidia-driver-515 nvidia-kernel-common-515 nvidia-kernel-source-515 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-515
  screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515
0 actualizados, 23 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
Se necesita descargar 380 MB de archivos.
Se utilizarán 979 MB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] s
Des:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 libnvidia-cfg1-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [93,5 kB]
Des:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 libnvidia-common-515 all 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [10,9 kB]
Des:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted i386 libnvidia-compute-515 i386 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [53,5 MB]
Des:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 libnvidia-compute-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [49,3 MB]
Des:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted i386 libnvidia-decode-515 i386 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [1.660 kB]                                                                                                             
Des:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 libnvidia-decode-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [1.443 kB]                                                                                                           
Des:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted i386 libnvidia-encode-515 i386 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [49,1 kB]                                                                                                              
Des:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 libnvidia-encode-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [45,7 kB]                                                                                                            
Des:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 libnvidia-extra-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [61,0 kB]                                                                                                             
Des:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 libnvidia-fbc1-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [51,6 kB]                                                                                                             
Des:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted i386 libnvidia-fbc1-515 i386 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [56,4 kB]                                                                                                               
Des:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted i386 libnvidia-gl-515 i386 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [25,9 MB]                                                                                                                 
Des:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 libnvidia-gl-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [188 MB]                                                                                                                
Des:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 nvidia-compute-utils-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [114 kB]                                                                                                        
Des:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 nvidia-kernel-source-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [31,2 MB]                                                                                                       
Des:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 nvidia-kernel-common-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [25,2 MB]                                                                                                       
Des:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 nvidia-dkms-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [31,9 kB]                                                                                                                
Des:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 nvidia-utils-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [359 kB]                                                                                                                
Des:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [1.475 kB]                                                                                                 
Des:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/restricted amd64 nvidia-driver-515 amd64 515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1 [467 kB]                                                                                                               
Des:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main amd64 nvidia-prime all 0.8.17.1 [9.956 B]                                                                                                                                                   
Des:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main amd64 screen-resolution-extra all 0.18.2 [4.396 B]                                                                                                                                          
Des:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main amd64 nvidia-settings amd64 510.47.03-0ubuntu1 [960 kB]                                                                                                                                     
Descargados 380 MB en 41s (9.267 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Seleccionando el paquete libnvidia-cfg1-515:amd64 previamente no seleccionado.
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 403517 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
Preparando para desempaquetar .../00-libnvidia-cfg1-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libnvidia-cfg1-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libnvidia-common-515 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../01-libnvidia-common-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando libnvidia-common-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libnvidia-compute-515:i386 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../02-libnvidia-compute-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Desempaquetando libnvidia-compute-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libnvidia-compute-515:amd64 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../03-libnvidia-compute-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libnvidia-compute-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libnvidia-decode-515:i386 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../04-libnvidia-decode-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Desempaquetando libnvidia-decode-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libnvidia-decode-515:amd64 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../05-libnvidia-decode-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libnvidia-decode-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libnvidia-encode-515:i386 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../06-libnvidia-encode-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Desempaquetando libnvidia-encode-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libnvidia-encode-515:amd64 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../07-libnvidia-encode-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libnvidia-encode-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libnvidia-extra-515:amd64 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../08-libnvidia-extra-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libnvidia-extra-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libnvidia-fbc1-515:amd64 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../09-libnvidia-fbc1-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libnvidia-fbc1-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../10-libnvidia-fbc1-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Desempaquetando libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libnvidia-gl-515:i386 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../11-libnvidia-gl-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
dpkg-query: no se ha encontrado ningún paquete que corresponda con libnvidia-gl-510.
Desempaquetando libnvidia-gl-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete libnvidia-gl-515:amd64 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../12-libnvidia-gl-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
dpkg-query: no se ha encontrado ningún paquete que corresponda con libnvidia-gl-510.
Desempaquetando libnvidia-gl-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete nvidia-compute-utils-515 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../13-nvidia-compute-utils-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando nvidia-compute-utils-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete nvidia-kernel-source-515 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../14-nvidia-kernel-source-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando nvidia-kernel-source-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete nvidia-kernel-common-515 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../15-nvidia-kernel-common-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando nvidia-kernel-common-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete nvidia-dkms-515 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../16-nvidia-dkms-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando nvidia-dkms-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete nvidia-utils-515 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../17-nvidia-utils-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando nvidia-utils-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../18-xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete nvidia-driver-515 previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../19-nvidia-driver-515_515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando nvidia-driver-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete nvidia-prime previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../20-nvidia-prime_0.8.17.1_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando nvidia-prime (0.8.17.1) ...
Seleccionando el paquete screen-resolution-extra previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../21-screen-resolution-extra_0.18.2_all.deb ...
Desempaquetando screen-resolution-extra (0.18.2) ...
Seleccionando el paquete nvidia-settings previamente no seleccionado.
Preparando para desempaquetar .../22-nvidia-settings_510.47.03-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando nvidia-settings (510.47.03-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando libnvidia-compute-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando libnvidia-compute-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando libnvidia-extra-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando nvidia-kernel-common-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Configurando nvidia-prime (0.8.17.1) ...
Configurando nvidia-kernel-source-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando libnvidia-decode-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando libnvidia-decode-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando screen-resolution-extra (0.18.2) ...
Configurando nvidia-utils-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando nvidia-settings (510.47.03-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando libnvidia-common-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando nvidia-dkms-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
Loading new nvidia-515.65.01 DKMS files...
Building for 5.19.0-21-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.19.0-21-generic
Done.

nvidia.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.19.0-21-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.19.0-21-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.19.0-21-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.19.0-21-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-peermem.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.19.0-21-generic/updates/dkms/
depmod...
Configurando libnvidia-fbc1-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando nvidia-compute-utils-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Warning: The home dir /nonexistent you specified can't be accessed: No such file or directory
Adding system user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 123) ...
Adding new group `nvidia-persistenced' (GID 130) ...
Adding new user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 123) with group `nvidia-persistenced' ...
Not creating home directory `/nonexistent'.
Configurando libnvidia-cfg1-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando libnvidia-encode-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando libnvidia-encode-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando libnvidia-gl-515:amd64 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando libnvidia-gl-515:i386 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Configurando nvidia-driver-515 (515.76+really.515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Procesando disparadores para desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu4) ...
Procesando disparadores para libc-bin (2.36-0ubuntu4) ...
Procesando disparadores para man-db (2.10.2-2) ...
Procesando disparadores para mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Procesando disparadores para initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu17) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-21-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda2
I: (UUID=06fef805-b5c7-4331-b08e-846079c87e7a)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

Comment: what is the issue, now that you've installed the nvidia driver successfully?

Comment: Nvidia driver refuses to be active, I could use the Intel igpu only.

Comment: Downgrading to Nvidia 510 did the magic and it works (CUDA included)

Comment: Why don't you either fix your /etc/X11/xorg.conf file, or rename it to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak, and reboot?

Comment: @heynnema I tried without success, but after back to 510 all works perfectly so I stopped trying 515.

Comment: @Buxato Did you try deleting/renaming the xorg.conf file? When you installed 515, are you sure that all of the 510 pieces were gone? `dpkg -l *nvidia*`. Did you install the CORRECT CUDA version? Is Secure Boot disabled?

Comment: @heynnema Yes I tried to delete and generate a new xorg.conf file, and also yes all 510 packages where removed. In fact I decide to try again 510 because I was reading that other persons had the same problem.

Comment: @Buxato You didn't do as I suggested. I said to delete/rename the xorg.conf file, not to create a new one... and is Secure Boot disabled... and did you install the CORRECT CUDA version? What version did you install? Are you running Wayland or X11? Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *nvidia*` and `nvidia-smi` and `dpkg -l *cuda*`.

Comment: @Buxato FYI Nvidia 520.56 is current as of Oct 12.

Comment: @Buxato Is this your configuration... Fixed a regression in 515.76 that caused blank screens and hangs when starting an X server on RTX 30 series GPUs in some configurations where the boot display is connected via HDMI

Comment: @heynnema well I partiallly did that, I removed the old xorg.conf file but yes I created one after that, sorry didn't understand you the first time. Yes the correct CUDA version was installed (albeit didn't know how CUDA could affect correct GPU detection). Always X11. Now I have 510 installed so I couldn't show you relevant versions output, but I will try 520 as you reported in few days when I finish some jobs.

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2